# How to find Effect Editor in Inkscape 0.92

Tags: inkscape

I've just switched from Inkscake 0.48 to 0.92. In Inkscape 0.48, there is a "Path Effect Editor" Under the menu "Path", But when I switch in 0.92, there is nos effect editor available there.I am attaching the screenshots [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAJgc.png), [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzXrZ.png), [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbKxA.png), and [four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJxLr.png)

My question is - How can I get this editing option in 0.92 (More specifically - How can I change the stroke width of pencil tool). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get by selecting "Patter Along Path" under Path Effet or just by selecting shape as Ellipse after selecting pencil tool.

[image]

[image]